# ajax and php sending useres in array

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, curl

I have a script that checks cpu cooling rates.

I want to store users in an array so I can cut the time checking them. I want to have a page where I can paste users in an array like this:

```
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
```

and send this via ajax to two variables in my PHP script, which are:

```
$user = "$mp[0]";
$password = "$mp[1]";
```

In summary, I want to send `user` to `$mp0` and `pass` to `$mp1` via an array.

Can someone point me in the direction?

Comment: can you rewrite your post so it focusses specifically on what you want to do? your description is not clear enough to understand your intention, and you example array is not an array. Please use a real example array (even if it only has 2 or 3 entries. More does not equal better when asking a question)

Comment: wat i mean bro is i want to pass User:pass to my php file user= $mp[0] and pass= $mp[1]

Comment: so the data will need splitting when it is sent via the array

Comment: thanks for the edit gibberish

Comment: What would expect to see in variables $user and $pass? Are they strings or arrays?

Comment: normally if i waas to do it manualy $user= in the php file i would input the user then in $pass = i would input the pass then when my script runs it logs in